# How to set fastlane credentials

Tags: ios, fastlane

I would like to set environmental variables i.e username using a command I tried

```
fastlane fastlane-credentials add --username me@myappleaccount.com
```

but I still get a prompt :

```
[10:30:31]: To not be asked about this value, you can specify it using 'username'
Your Apple ID Username:
```

I work in a team of developers and I would like to have an ability to for every developer to set there own username without committing the files with different username. Is there a command for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experiences using the command you mentioned, but we use `dotenv` files for all kind of variables and those work like a charm. Some of them are under version control and some are developer specific.

How to use `dotenv` files is described [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/other/#environment-variables). We use both the automatically loaded `dotenv` files and some manually loaded ones.

Answer (score 1):

Run in your terminal `export FASTLANE_USER=your@email.com`

This will set the variable with your email.

You can then run fastlane